# Case insensitive MongoDB query from Go

Tags: go, mgo

I have this json file:

```
[{
    "name": "chetan",
    "age": 23,
    "hobby": ["cricket", "football"]
}, {
    "name": "raj",
    "age": 24,
    "hobby": ["cricket", "golf"]
}]
```

I use this Go code to search the data:

```
id := "ket" 
regex := bson.M{"$regex": bson.RegEx{Pattern: id}} 
err = c.Find(bson.M{"hobby": regex}).All(&result)
```

It finds if searched by the same string like "cricket" but if I search string like this "Cricket", it does not find it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add `Options: "i"` to your RegEx.

```
bson.M{"$regex": bson.RegEx{Pattern: id, Options: "i"}}
```