# User search with Golang mgo

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

Getting a string as input (from a user search), I am trying to construct a `bson.M` object for `mgo` to search through the mongo database and find x number of items.

Something like this

```golang
func Search (w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    q := r.FormValue("q")
    filter := bson.M{}
    // magic happens here 

    // do db connection stuff
    things := []*thing{}
    err := db.Find(&filter).Limit(10).All(&things)
    // check error, send things, etc
}
```

What I need the search to be based on is

- ignore case (I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37340539/case-insensitive-mongodb-query-from-go) which takes me part of the way)
- the `title` in the stored data must, somewhere, include each of the words in the `q`.

So for instance if the stored data looks like `{title: "abcde"}`, then

- `Abc` will match
- `de Bc` will match
- `ac` will not match

## Edit: Solution

I finally figured it out. The magic part looks like this:

```
q := r.FormValue("q")
qs := strings.Split(q, " ")
and := make([]bson.M, len(qs))
for i, q := range qs {
    and[i] = bson.M{"title": bson.M{
        "$regex": bson.RegEx{Pattern: ".*" + q + ".*", Options: "i"},
    }}
}
filter := bson.M{"$and": and}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mongo filter can take regex, for example;

```
        bson.M{"title": bson.M{"$regex": bson.RegEx{Pattern: title, Options: "i"}}}
```

So in this case the title variable would be something like; `.*abc*.`. The Options: "i" enables case insensitivity.

As for matching the substring (scenario 2) I am not sure how to achieve within regex.

Comment: Thanks! – `Pattern: title` ? You mean `Pattern: q` right? And do you know how to do if `q` consists of more than one word?

Comment: Yes, but you need to add the relevant regex and I would suggest escaping/validating the input to ensure you are not exposed to a NoSql injection style attack.

Comment: Regarding the multiple words. I would imagine you can do some sort of string split and then use the $and keyword to chain the regex. (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/and/)

Comment: I feel I should be able to, but even that won't work for me. The googling continues..

Comment: I'll accept your answer since it was the answer that helped me the most, and so the question is considered to have a solution. :)

Answer (score 0):

Simple use this,

```
wordOffset := q

selector:= bson.M{"title": bson.M{"$regex": wordOffset}}
```